# My invokable apex doesn't appear to run from @wire

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a LWC that is supposed to call Apex method but looking at the debug logs it seems like it just doesn't run the apex at all. This was working fine with just `accountId` property but now I've added `isPending` property it no longer works.

NWSGetResponseRecords.cls

```
public with sharing class NWSGetResponseRecords {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Network_Search_Response__c> getResponseRecords(String accountId, Boolean isPending) {
        system.debug('accountId apex -> ' + accountId);
        system.debug('isPending apex -> ' + isPending);
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Stage__c, Is_Pending__c, End_Date__c, Global_Parent_Name__c, Maxis_Network_Search_Owner__c FROM Network_Search_Response__c WHERE Member__c =:accountId AND Is_Pending__c =:isPending];
    }
}
```

networkSearchRelatedLists.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <template if:true={responses.data}>
            hello world
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

networkSearchRelatedLists.js

```
import { LightningElement , api, wire } from "lwc";
import getResponseRecords from '@salesforce/apex/NWSGetResponseRecords.getResponseRecords';

export default class NetworkSearchRelatedLists extends LightningElement {
    @api accountId;
    @api isPending;
    
    @wire(getResponseRecords, {accountId: '$accountId', isPending: '$isPending'})
    responses;
}
```

networkSearchRelatedLists.js-meta.xml

```
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>54.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Network search related list</masterLabel>
    <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="accountId" type="String" label="AccountId" required="true" />
            <property name="isPending" type="Boolean" description="Set depending if you want to show pending or submitted network search responses" label="Is pending"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

`Is_Pending__c` is a formula field on Network_Search_Response__c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hadn't set `isPending` to be a boolean in `networkSearchRelatedLists.js`.

Should have been @api `isPending = false;`